# PhD funding with a Pass at Masters?

Tags: phd, thesis, masters, funding

So, I just finished my Masters at a top University in the UK but I was awarded a Pass. I recently met up with a potential supervisor at another top institution about my proposed topic - and she really likes me, loves the research, and has been sending me funding information.

However, how do I get around the fact that I got a poor grade on my MSc for funding applications? Some of the funding offers a chance for students to do a MSc then a PhD. Is it wrong to apply to these and not even say that I did a Masters? It feels like I'd have been better off.

To add to this, I actually have a very good record of research experience, and my transcript for the MSc is good. I just lost marks on my thesis which meant I couldn't get a Merit (or 2:1).

I'm so worried, I want nothing more than to do a PhD, particularly on the topic I proposed (community stigma, mental health). I really don't want this to set me back!

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that not having a merit will significantly impact your chances of getting funding? Maybe you're right, maybe you're wrong, but I didn't get a merit for my MSc and I never heard any suggestion that it would be an obstacle when I was looking for PhD funding.

Comment: I think this is based on the potential competition for funding places. I would assume the better the qualifications, the more likely you are to receive funding. Do you think a strong proposal and experience in research is considered more valuable?

Comment: I would imagine so. There are so many other factors (e.g., research experience, the proposal, publications, content of the masters, etc.) that I can't imagine whether or not the candidate received a merit/distinction as being that important in the decision.